# Wordpress Sidebar/Widget Menu different on remote server

Tags: wordpress, widget, themes

I've developed a Wordpress theme locally and everything is groovy. On uploading to our production server and going back into the Widgets area the backend screens are different and my widgets are not displaying.

Here's the sidebar code:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(1) ) : else : ?>

        <li>
        <h2><?php _e('Categories'); ?></h2>
            <ul>
            <?php wp_list_cats('sort_column=name&hierarchical=0'); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
        <h2><?php _e('Archives'); ?></h2>
            <ul>
            <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like in both server environments. 
[image: My local Wordpress enviornment vs the remote one]

So the questions(s): Why would they be different? How can I fix the Remote Server, or how Can I refrence the way the Remote Server is setup correctly in my theme.

Comment: hi, I posted an answer below, but is there a reason why your version are out of sync?

Comment: I already had 3.2.1 set up locally, and was asked to develop a theme for prod, which the server team hasn't updated in a while. Thanks for the answer, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe widget data is stored in the wp_options table, have you updated the proper values in there?

Be careful transferring that table as it may screw up your site (fairly easily fixable though).

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-is-widget-data-stored-in-the-database

The above link may help, just do the search as instructed and try moving the returned value to prod. PLEASE BACK UP THAT TABLE BEFORE DOING SO.

I don't want to be hunted down and killed </sarcasm> if my answer eradicates your site.

-p

Comment: I'm not going to have access to change those tables. Any idea how to refrence those bars in code?

Comment: As I couldn't do this the official way, I uninstalled and reinstalled the theme a few times and WP did the same thing for me.